# Error concatenating directory path in bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a simple bash file and want to execute a cd command:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir_path="~/Desktop/param_bind_b"
cd $dir_path
```

for some reason, when I try to run this script in terminal, I get this error:

> student@ubuntu:~$ openptv_current_install.bash 
>   /home/student/Desktop/scripts/openptv_current_install.bash: line 3:
>   cd: ~/Desktop/param_bind_b: No such file or directory

when I run the command `cd ~/Desktop/param_bind_b` "manually" it runs as expected.

what am I missing here?

Comment: Use `$HOME` instead of `~` in scripts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tilde (`~`) will not be expanded by shell when put inside quotes. Just remove the quotes :

```
#!/bin/bash
dir_path=~/Desktop/param_bind_b
cd "$dir_path"
```

Answer (score 3):

An other solution is, place only the `~` outside the quotes or use `$HOME` instead. Additionally you should add `|| exit` behind `cd`.

```
#!/bin/bash
dir_path=~"/Desktop/param_bind_b"
cd "$dir_path" || exit
```

Or

```
#!/bin/bash
dir_path="$HOME/Desktop/param_bind_b"
cd "$dir_path" || exit
```

so you can use other variables, E.G.

```
#!/bin/bash
desktop_dir="/Desktop"
dir_path=~"$desktop_dir/param_bind_b"
cd "$dir_path" || exit
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
desktop_dir="/Desktop"
dir_path=~"$desktop_dir"/param_bind_b
cd "$dir_path" || exit
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
desktop_dir="/Desktop"
dir_path="$HOME$desktop_dir"/param_bind_b
cd "$dir_path" || exit
```

In the future, check your scripts [here](http://www.shellcheck.net/). **;)**